# GeoSpatial queries and indexes in memory

Tags: geojson, proximity

I am currently using Spark/Scala to process some data, and I am at the point that I need to run ~3M of geospatial queries. One common solution would be using MongoDB or PostGIS (or Magellan for Spark which I already know it has not what I am looking for at the moment).

The queries are the classical Proximity queries for GeoJSON/WGS84 to find out, given a point "A", what are the 100 nearest points to "A" in a radius of 1 Mile within a set "B" of similar points.

Is there any library that helps you to do this sort of queries in memory and a library that can create (always in memory) indexes (2DSphere/Geohash?) for the set "B"?

Comment: Is set "B" large or small?  Specifically, does "B" fit in memory?  I'm guessing that if asking to fit an index for "B" in memory, then yes, "B" is of size that can fit in memory.

Comment: Yes both fit in memory. B file is 500mb on filesystem divided roughly in 1M records.

Answer (score 3):

You can build an [in-memory quadtree](http://esri.github.io/geometry-api-java/javadoc/com/esri/core/geometry/QuadTree.html) with the [Esri Geometry API for Java](https://github.com/Esri/geometry-api-java), as in the [point-in-polygon sample in the GIS Tools for Hadoop](https://github.com/Esri/gis-tools-for-hadoop/tree/master/samples/point-in-polygon-aggregation-mr).

[Disclosure - collaborator on the GIS Tools for Hadoop.]

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is very interesting. I assume you are referring to the code in https://github.com/Esri/gis-tools-for-hadoop/blob/master/samples/point-in-polygon-aggregation-mr/src/com/esri/hadoop/examples/MapperClass.java

Comment: has it sense to have as minimum bounding geometry a circle with the search radius of 1 Mile in the geohash (if it is possible)?

Comment: well a circular bounding geometry might be not good. You can just have a squared envelope, check if the point is in the region and check if the distance from the centre of the region is within 1 Mile.

Comment: Yes, MapperClass.java